# Regex to ignore specific words before and after a group of words anywhere in the sentence

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regex:

```
 (?!.*\bno\b.*\b(text|sample text)\b)(?!.*\b(text|sample text)\b .*not).+
```

Example:
https://regex101.com/r/Epq0Ns/17 
 
To match pattern in sentences like:

- anything with 'no' followed by (group of words) or a 'not' should not be matched

**should not match:** first sentence with no and sample text

**should not match:** second with a text but also a not

**should not match:** third has a no, a text and a not

**should match:** fourth alone is what is needed with just text

**should match:** this can be matched as output

Comment: And?  What's your questions?

Comment: @Alfe with the current regex, the first 3 sentences also get matched.

Comment: You have to anchor your pattern.

Comment: Please provide some more realistic input strings - actually no regex is needed. Just split on the whitespace per sentence and check with `... in ...`

Comment: @Jan     Examples:  Not match: There is no sample text related to this topic and is not needed 

**Not match:** No text books are needed at this point 

**Match:** The text is related to the content we proposed

Comment: Use `\b(no|not)\b` as a regexp and negate the output.  I take your question as a Specification-By-Example and provide this first draft solution and urge you to extend your example input/output pairs to be more precise.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Anchoring the pattern did not return any results at all     
`(r'^(?!.*\bno\b.*\b(text|sample text)\b)(?!.*\b(text|sample text)\b .*not).+')`

Comment: @sagar: use the m modifier as in your regex101 link. [example](https://regex101.com/r/Jh2kSA/2)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I use the regex in a python function, like the below `result = regex(series1,(r'^(?!.*\bno\b.*\b(?:sample )?text\b)(?!.*\b(?:sample )?text\b .*not).+')` and I get  value error `ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups`

Comment: Put the whole line in a capture group or edit the function to extract the whole match.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte It works in this [link](https://regex101.com/r/Epq0Ns/20). But not in the python function. Cannot figure out why.

Comment: @sagar: Sorry but without the function code (and what it is supposed to do) I can't help you.